Exporting Power BI pagination report to csv
When exporting Power BI pagination report table in csv, I do not want to show the text boxes how to do it?I gave the below code but it did not work
=IIF(Globals!RenderFormat.Name = "CSV", True, False)
Is there any other way to hide text box when exporting to csv?

